# Server Speed for specific appliaction with an mounted network share

Tags: nfs, mount, windows-server-2019

I have a windows server running windows server 2019
This server is hosting an emby server [media streaming]
The media is hosted an a mounted disk from an s3 provider with rclone

When trying to watch video with bitrate over 10 mbps it keeps freezing, Is there something limiting the speed of the application?
With the server link 1Gbps dedicated.

I have messed with my settings multiple times but not sure where to look, even disabled firewall, different port.
The server can download very fast.

Thank you guys for any help.

Comment: `The media is hosted an a mounted disk from an s3 provider with rclone` - It's almost a  certainty that's where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I would say you are right but the download speed is very high my system having issues sending me the file.